# What is the range of convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k \cdot x \exp(-x))^k\cdot {1 \over k!} \cdot {1\over k+1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following series as an expression which occurs as a limit of a quotient of polynomials in $e$ and $x$ which I've expanded by polynomial long division into a series:
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \Big({k \cdot x \over e^x}\Big)^k\cdot {1 \over k!} \cdot 
{1\over k+1}$$
I'm interested in the convergence/divergence of this power series for the argument in the range $ x \gt 0$.

---

This is what I have done so far:
Let
$$ c_k(x)=\Big({k \cdot x \over e^x}\Big)^k\cdot {1 \over k!}  $$
and let by the Stirling-approximation
$$\Big({k \over e}\Big)^k\cdot {1 \over k!} \approx {1\over \sqrt{2 \pi }}{1\over \sqrt{k}} $$

Then for the k'th term I get

1. with $x=1$ the approximation
   $$ c_k(1)\cdot {1\over k+1} \approx {1\over \sqrt{2 \pi }}{1\over k^{1.5}} $$
   I think this is sufficient to show convergence (compared for instance with the Dirichlet-series zeta(1.5)).
2. If $x \gt 1$ the terms $c_k(x)$ decrease and thus I think the series is obviously even more convergent, so I assume that we have convergence for $x \ge 1$.

---

However, for $0<x<1$ it is not so obvious at the moment.

> ***Q***: Is there a (possibly similar simple) argument for the convergence in the remaining range $0<x<1$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ratio test:

$\displaystyle \lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{a_{k+1}(x)}{a_{k}(x)}=\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{\Big({(k+1) \cdot x \over e^x}\Big)^{k+1}\cdot {1 \over (k+1)! }\frac{1}{k+2}}{\Big({k \cdot x \over e^x}\Big)^k\cdot {1 \over k!}\frac{1}{k+1}}=\lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{x}{e^x} \frac{k+1}{k+2}(1+\frac{1}{k})^k=\frac{x}{e^{x-1}}$

But $x<e^{x-1}$ for $x \neq 1$, so the series converges for $x \neq 1$.

Comment: Ahh, yes. I got it; better for me were the form to write $e^x \ge 1+x$ - and it is simply visible because the following terms of the exponential-series $1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!+...$ are missing. So this is "obvious" for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $y = xe^{-x}$. Then, the series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k \cdot y)^k\cdot {1 \over k!} \cdot {1\over k+1}$ converges for all $|y| < R$ for some radius of convergence $R$. (This is a property of power series)

As you have shown, the series converges for $x = 1$, i.e. $y = \dfrac{1}{e}$. So, we know that $R \ge \dfrac{1}{e}$.

The function $f(x) = xe^{-x}$ has derivative $f'(x) = (1-x)e^{-x}$. So, $f'(x) > 0$ for $0 < x < 1$, and $f'(x) < 0$ for $x > 1$. Therefore, for all $x \ge 0$, we have $f(x) \le f(1)$, i.e. $y = xe^{-x} \le \dfrac{1}{e} \le R$.

Therefore, the series converges for all $x \ge 0$.

Comment: Ah, I needed two times to read and understand this completely. This explains even more for me than the other answer - if I hadn't "accepted"that before I'd accept this now. Thank you very much!